# JavaScript array value to variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, reference

I am trying to get into Fuse to create mobile apps and they use JavaScript for their logic. I never used JavaScript before and just recently completed their getting started course. Most of the stuff is pretty easy to understand, but I am having trouble with the way they use variables at one point. It would be nice, if somebody could explain how variables behave in JavaScript.

So the problem I have goes as follows:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < hikes.length; i++){
        // A new variable gets the value of the array
        var hike = hikes[i];

        if (hike.id == id){
            // The variable gets a new value
            hike.name = "foo";
            break;
        }
    }
```

So, in my understanding of programming, the array hikes should be unchanged and only the variable hike should have foo as the name value. But in reality, the array now also has the name foo.

I guess the variable works as a pointer to the address of the arrays value, but maybe somebody can help me to better understand that concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you're right, objects and arrays are always passed as references:

```
a = {}; // empty object
b = a; // references same object
b.foo = 'bar';
a.foo; // also 'bar'
```

Comment: This does not answer the question

Answer (score 1):

You can create a deep copy of the array using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(hikes));` and then use that copied array for manipulation:

```js
var hikes = [
  {
    'id': 10
  }
];
var id = 10;
var tempHikes = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(hikes));
for (var i = 0; i < tempHikes.length; i++){
    // A new variable gets the value of the array
    var hike = tempHikes[i];
    if (hike.id == id){
        // The variable gets a new value
        hike.name = "foo";
        console.log('hike is ', hike);
        break;
    }
}
console.log(hikes);
```

Answer (score 1):

arrays in javascript are passed by reference, whenever you modify an element in an array that change will occur anywhere you are accessing that array, to avoid such issues you have to use `Array.from(arg)` which creates a new array of from the `arg` parameter. This also applies to objects, to avoid such issues with objects, you have to use `Object.create(obj)` to create a new obj of from `obj` parameter or you can use `let newObj = Object.assign( {} , obj )` , whenever you make any modification to the members of `newObj` the `obj` object does not see it, in other words there is no direct linkage between this two object, same thing applies for array

Answer (score 0):

`Boolean`, `null`, `undefined`, `String`, and `Number` values are called *primitive types*.

When you assign something that is *not* a primitive type, namely **arrays**, **functions** and **objects** you are storing a *reference* to that.
That means that `hikes[i]` contains a *reference* to the object, where *reference* **roughly** means a pointer to it's location in memory.

When you assign `hike = hikes[i]` you are copying over the *reference* and not the actual object. So in fact `hike` still points to the same object as `hikes[i]`, so any changes to that object are visible on both occasions.

If you want to *copy* the underlying object, there are different ways of doing so. One of them is [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
var hike = Object.assign({}, hikes[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of pass by reference. All you need to do is create a new object (string, number ...) that you can work on.

```js
 for (var i = 0; i < hikes.length; i++){
    var hike = hikes.slice(i,i+1)[0];
    if (hike.id == id){
        hike.name = "foo";
        break;
    }
}
```

slice also create a deep copy. you can use splice or assign or ((key1, key2)=>(key1, key2))(obj) etc.